# How to get copy.com notification icon on Unity on Trusty to work?

Tags: unity, system-tray

Do you guys know how to get Copy's systray icon to work?

That's an old question and the old fix doesn't work no more..

I've already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

and the other:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

and since [Ubuntu retired whitelisting](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/raring-retires-system-tray-whitelist) (partially in 13.04 and - as my understanding goes - totally in 14.04: there is no `com.canonical.Unity.Panel` schema at all), do you guys have a fix for that?

**Edit:** I ultimately made the systray icon show up by doing the two last commands and creating a folder `.icons` in my home folder.

```
mkdir -p ~/.icons
```

But  the menu is still messed up:

[image: Copy menu grayed]

Any suggestions?

P.S: I think we might be close to what seems to be a fix..

Comment: I'm facing same problem. Need to get a effective solution, quickly !!!

Comment: My to. The missing systray are really annoying.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457675/the-indicator-icon-of-copy-com-disappeared-or-the-menu-is-unreadable/ is a similar question with an answer added that fixes the problem.

Comment: My question came first! lol Anyway this doesn't solve my problem since I have x86_64 system. Thanks.

Comment: copy support says they are aware and "may" in a future version blablablah - thanks for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the same issue that has been described in the link below. The issue persists on 13.04 to 14.04.
 This has been fixed in 14.10 but temporarily you can find the solution here:
[Fix Copy.com indicator menu for Ubuntu 14.04/13.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/fix-copycom-indicator-menu-for-ubuntu.html)
Hope it helps

Comment: Yep I've seen it along with this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217713&page=4&p=13043274#post13043274 but this bug made me switch to Kubuntu 14.04 and I believe the KDE desktop will be my main desktop for really long time.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it, but unfortunately not the pretty way (meaning I did not know, what I am doing). 
First I did what you did and then followed on this site [copy help forum](https://copy.zendesk.com/entries/28050018-Ubuntu-13-10-indicator-icon-?page=2)
the instructions of user "January Weiner" .
I have no idea, but perhaps that was the crucial point:

```
cd ~/.copy
echo 'UPDATE config2 SET value=0 WHERE option="csmBlackWhiteIconsV2" ;' | sqlite3 config.db
echo 'UPDATE config2 SET value=0 WHERE option="csmGlobalSync" ;' | sqlite3 config.db
echo 'UPDATE config2 SET value=0 WHERE option="csmAppIndicatorAvailable" ;' | sqlite3 config.db
```

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit system? This guy (http://askubuntu.com/questions/457675/the-indicator-icon-of-copy-com-disappeared-or-the-menu-is-unreadable/#457680) had an almost similar solution but it doesn't seem to work with 64-bit systems. Your solution alos doesn't work with 64-bit systems; I've tested it to make sure.

Comment: yes I have a 64 bit system, perhaps a interesting detail, all my indicators work as well with left click as with right click, only copy even now looking perfectly fine has its drop down menu only accessible by right click, but except for that its really working well. To bad the copy support seems not interested they probably could clarify much.