# Copy (cloud storage) icon doesn't appear on the Panel

Tags: 14.04, unity, indicator, panel, notification-area

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity. Since Ubuntu One is no more I am using [Copy](http://www.copy.com) . But I can't see the copy icon in the notification area of the Panel. I am sure that copy is running in the background because the System Monitor app says so. I have libappindicator1 and libappindicator3-1. installed. Yet I don't see the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Copy.com will work and the indicator will show on the menu bar but the pull down is useless in 14.04. Copy does know this 'and may' fix in an upcoming release. The best you can do is download the tar file - expand it to your home folder.

You will have a copy folder - note the lower case 'C'. Then open the enclosed folder according to your system, 32 or 64 bits. There is a readme file in the folder.

For my 64 bit box I opened the x86_64 folder and double clicked the CopyAgent icon (file), then signed into my Copy account. To be double sure I opened a terminal and navigated to ~/copy/x86_64 and ran

[code]

```
sudo ./CopyAgent installOverlay
```

[/code]

You should also see here: [The indicator icon of Copy.com disappeared or the menu is unreadable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457675/the-indicator-icon-of-copy-com-disappeared-or-the-menu-is-unreadable) & [How to get copy.com notification icon on Unity on Trusty to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449331/how-to-get-copy-com-notification-icon-on-unity-on-trusty-to-work)